# Issue when print <script> tag

Tags: php

Hi I am receiving the following error with the below code:

```
<?php
echo '<script>
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        placeholder: 'Hello Bootstrap 4',
        tabsize: 2,
        height: 250
    });
</script>';
?>
```

I can not print this JavaScript code using "echo" in PHP, it shows:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'placeholder' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\NoteApp\layout\Header.php on line 17"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have single quotes in your JavaScript code which you're also using to delimit the string.

You could fiddle with single and double quotes to get it right, but there's no need to echo it from PHP. Just drop out of PHP for that part of your code:

```
<?php
// PHP code here
?>

<!-- This section is just sent to the output -->
<script>
            $('#summernote').summernote({
                placeholder: 'Hello Bootstrap 4',
                tabsize: 2,
                height: 250
            });
</script>

<?php
// More PHP code here
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have single quotes nested in your single-quoted string.  Try using double-quotes in the Javascript code.